# What are the differences between these two methods of using the put command?

Tags: ruby

```
var = 5

puts "Method #1: #{var}"
puts "Method #2: %d" % var
```

I'm looking for advantages and drawbacks with each method, if there are at all.

Comment: Note that the fact that you're using `puts` is irrelevant, both of these are perfectly valid expressions without the `puts`.

Comment: That I realized. It has more to do with string formatting/manipulation than `puts` keyword, right?

Comment: Yup, the former is just regular string interpolation, and the later is actually a [method on String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is simple string interpolation, while the second is syntactic sugar for [Kernel#sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

Use the first for cases where you just need to generate a string that includes variable data in it. The second is better for when you need to do specialized formatting beyond just putting  a variable into a string. The first will have better performance, so do it that way unless you need specialized formatting.

And it case it comes up, `"hello #{var}"` is much faster than `"hello " + var`.

Comment: It's not "syntactic sugar for sprintf", it's the `String#%` method.